# Is there a Button class that looks like this?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I have seen a button like this, but I don't know what it is called.  The knob can be slided over Option 2, then on the left the chosen Option (Option 2) should be displayed in green.

Any ideas what this is called or if there is a ready made class?

[image: button with slider]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is called toogle button, reference here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton

Answer (score 0):

That's called a Switch, its available on API level 14+
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch

if you want to target API level 7+ you can use SwitchCompat
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat

Comment: The switch is very close, but has an On / Off bias.  I am looking for something that chooses between two options.